# Semantic html page structure

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I want to build a semantic html page with a two column layout. Which is the correct way to structure the page. Please take note of where the aside is placed.

**Option 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <section class="col-1"></section>
    <aside class="col-2"></aside>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Option 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main class="col-1">
    <section></section>
    <aside></aside>
  </main>
  <aside class="col-2"></aside>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Which option is correct?

Comment: Is it correct that your option 2 also contains `aside` in `main`? If yes, what is it used for, and why does option 1 only need one `aside`?

Comment: both asides will contain banner ads

Comment: And what does the additional `aside` in option 2 contain? (option 1 doesn’t have it) -- To answer a semantic markup question, it’s important to describe what the content is, so it would help to add to the examples e.g. comments like `<!-- banner ad -->`.